# front gear shifter cable sleeve, shifter to frame needs replacing, the old wire rusted inside

Tags: gears, shifter, cable

bought this bike 2nd hand from charity shop,
front gear shifter was sticky and wouldn't shift to 3 [3+8 setup] as was already at 3. [streached?]

''bloke who brought it in said it just needs oiling'',
i was told,

i was doubtful, but thought at werst, a new 'gear lever'.
i got new shifter, then noticed strands of rusty wire,
first at frame end of sleeve, then [after removing sleeve] at shifter end.
this 'bloke' had chopped the wire at each end of cable sleeve, fitted new cable, then, [i think], started gouging the 'lever travel slot' [presumably to facilitate the applying of wd40 etc].

story over!,
Ques: can i just get a sleeve [of suitable lenght] from wherever, or are there many different sizes [external/ internal]?.
if this is critical, where should i look for replacement?.
regards dave.

Comment: Can you please add a clean, clear, and well-lit photo of the shifter, and the rear derailleur?

Answer (score 2):

By sleeve I presume you are meaning the Shifter cable outer.  If this is the case, yes, any shifter cable will do. Easiest way to to get a 'kit' that comprises of shifter inner and outer and endcaps. Only thing to note is there  are different ends for MTB and road bike shifters. Also brake cables are thicker and the outer will not make a good shifter cable outer due different construction.

The cable (both inner and outer) can be hard to cut without proper cable cutters. There are various methods that work e.g. Dremel. If not using proper cutters, I suggest practicing on the old cables before attempting to cut the new one to the correct length.